# PHP code works on Chrome, but not on Firefox or IE

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms, email

**My brother has this form:**

```
<form id="lista" action="lista2.php" method="post">

<input name="cf_name" type="text" size="50" hidden="yes" class="obscure">
<input name="cf_email" type="text" size="50" hidden="yes" class="obscure">
<textarea name="cf_message" cols="45" rows="10" hidden="yes" class="obscure">
</textarea>
<input type="image" name="submit" value="Enviar Lista por Email" src="imagens/lista_email.png" width="40" height="40" 
onclick="this.form.elements['cf_message'].value = lista_mail;this.form.elements['cf_name'].value = prompt('Escreva o seu nome:', '');this.form.elements['cf_email'].value = prompt('Escreva o seu email:', '');">
<input name="submit2" type="submit" value="Enviar" hidden="yes" class="obscure"> 

</form>
```

**That calls this PHP file:**

```
<?php

if ( isset($_POST['submit']) ) {

// Dados de autenticacao SMTP
$smtpinfo['host'] = 'localhost';
$smtpinfo['port'] = '25';
$smtpinfo['auth'] = true;
$smtpinfo['username'] = 'xxx';
$smtpinfo['password'] = 'xxx';

// Dados recebidos do formulario
$nome = $_POST['cf_name'];
$email = $_POST['cf_email'];
$mensagem = $_POST['cf_message'];

// Inclusão de ficheiro PEAR. Certifique-se que o PEAR está activado no seu alojamento
require_once "Mail.php";

// Corpo da mensagem
$body = "Nome: ".$nome;
$body.= "\n\n";
$body.= nl2br($mensagem);

$headers = array ('From' => $email,
'To' => $smtpinfo["username"],
'Subject' => 'Encomenda Website');

$mail_object = Mail::factory('smtp', $smtpinfo);

$mail = $mail_object->send($smtpinfo["username"], $headers, $body);

if ( PEAR::isError($mail) ) {
echo ("<p>" . $mail->getMessage() . "</p>");
} else {
echo ('<b><font color="FFFF00">Mensagem enviada com sucesso.<br><br></b>Seu email: ' . $email . '<br><br></font>');
}}

?>
```

This basically sends an email with some selected products, name and email.

The problem is that it works perfectly on Chrome, but not on FF or IE. When the **submit** image is pressed, the URL changes to the PHP file, but it displays a blank page.

**Edit:**

**Added this:**

```
ini_set('display_errors',1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors',1);
error_reporting(-1)
```

FF/IE display blank page and email isn't sent, Chrome sends the email and displays this:

```
Strict Standards: Non-static method Mail::factory() should not be called statically in /var/www/vhosts/[site url]/httpdocs/lista2.php on line 33
Strict Standards: Non-static method PEAR::isError() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in /usr/share/php/Mail/smtp.php , dont know if it helps
```

The tip about the "hidden" fields, also didn't help.

Comment: Turn errors on. There is going to be defiantly some warning or error.

Comment: Try replacing `hidden="yes"` with `type="hidden"`

Comment: and why `textarea` hidden or `class="obscure"`?

Comment: aldanux, the "hidden" replacement didn't made any difference :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was in: `if ( isset($_POST['submit']) ) {`

because it was a image, and not a regular submit button, it was never set. (but somehow google chrome managed to put it to work)

solution was to add to form: `<input name="submit2" type="hidden" value="1"/>`

and change the PHP to: `if ( isset($_POST['submit2']) ) {`

Answer (score 0):

It may depend on the software you are using to build your pages.

I use Aptana Studio and I found that if you select run from the menu bar,
and then run configurations, you can specify in the server dialog
to use base url (your server)

I'm pretty sure dreamweaver has similar settings.